# When is it possible to extend a set function not defined on a semiring to a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I have a class $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of a nonempty and uncountable set $\Omega$. $\mathcal{C}$ is not a semiring. As I know, $\mathcal{C}$ is a semiring if the followings are true:
(1) $\emptyset\in\mathcal{C}$
(2) $A,B\in\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow A\cap B\in\mathcal{C}$
(3) If $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$ and $A\subset B$, then there exist pairwise disjoint $C_1,\cdots,C_n\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $B\setminus A=\cup_{i=1}^nC_i$.

My $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies (1) and (3). In addition, $\Omega\in\mathcal{C}$. But it does not satisfy (2). Hence $\mathcal{C}$ is not a semiring. Moreover, $A\cap B$ may not be able to be written as finite union of disjoint elements in $\mathcal{C}$.

I also have a set function $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal{C}$. $\mu$ satisfies
(a) $\mu(\emptyset)=0$; $\mu(\Omega)=1$
(b) If $A_1,\cdots,A_n\in\mathcal{C}$ are pairwise disjoint and $\cup_{i=1}^nA_i\in\mathcal{C}$, then $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^nA_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)$.
(c) For $A,B\in\mathcal{C}$ with $A\subset B$, $\mu(B)\geq\mu(A)$.

I want to ask when can I extend $\mu$ to be a probability measure (just finitely additive is fine)? As I know, I cannot use Caratheodory Extension Theorem because $\mathcal{C}$ is not a semiring. Is there any other condition on $\mathcal{C}$ which can give me an extension? (or other condition on $\mu$?)

I encounter such problem in my research project. My goal is to prove that there exist a probability measure which agrees with $\mu$ on $\mathcal{C}$. Now I know that $\mathcal{C}$ does not satisfy (2). So I try to find other sufficient conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is hopeless. You need some condition that guarantees countable additivity and you have none. Let $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ consists of those sets that are finite or have a finite complement. Every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ forms even an algebra. Define $\mu$ on $\mathcal{C}$ by letting $\mu(F)=0$ and $\mu(\Omega\setminus F)=1$ if $F$ is finite. If $\mu$ would extend to a measure on every subset of $\mathbb{N}$, we would have
$$0=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}0=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(\{n\})=\mu(\mathbb{N})=1.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How about if I just require finitely additivity? (I just edited my post. Thanks for reminding me this point.)